# Transform a list of Char to a list of ints C#

Tags: c#

so i've been trying a lot to transform a list of chars like this `[20,8,25,5,34,12]` into a list of just ints. I'm currently doing it this
way:

```
string fromJson = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + "/JsonSaveTest.json");
List<int> temp = GetNumbers(fromJson).Select(c => int.Parse(c)).ToList();
```

and then

```
private List<string> GetNumbers(string input)
{
    List<char> temp = input.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToList();
    var toReturn = temp.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToList();      
    return toReturn;

}
```

but it separates every single number on its own, like the result list should be 20 8 25 5 34 12 and it actually comes out like 2 0 8 2 5 5 3 4 1 2.

Comment: If this is a Json text why don't you use a json library to read it back as it was intended to be?

Comment: Well you iterate over the string `"[20,8,25,5,34,12]"`. So it will process char-by-char.

Comment: How about stripping the first and last characters, then splitting the remaining string on comma ","? Then iterate through the array of strings and parse them into ints. (Or use LINQ instead of a loop, but that's the basic approach I'd take.)

Comment: Is "[20,8,25,5,34,12]" a single string or is it more like ["20","8","25","5","34","12"]?  If it's the latter, using the `char` datatype is probably a fumble.

Comment: Strongly recommend using the NewtonSoft JSON library for working with JSON in C#, rather than trying to write code to deserialize the JSON yourself.  Trust me you'll be glad you did in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your sample list:

```
"[20,8,25,5,34,12]"
```

The easiest way is to break the `string` apart after removing the brackets, and cast the `array` from `string.Split()` using its `ToList()` function.

```
private List<string> GetNumbers(string input)
{
  string x = input.Replace("[", string.Empty).Replace("]",string.Empty); 
  return x.Split(',').ToList();
}
```

Note: The JSON-related answer is the "proper" way.  This is more the quick-and-dirty "any list of strings will do" way.

Comment: I know this isnt't the perfect way to solve it but it did help and it works now. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If the string is in the format you specified (e.g. "[20,8,25,5,34,12]"), you can simply use JsonConvert from the Newtonsoft.Json package:

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>("[20,8,25,5,34,12]");
```

This is assuming that you want a list of integers, as stated in your question. If you want a list of strings of numbers, use

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>("[20,8,25,5,34,12]");
```

instead

Comment: This answer originally had a Unity3d tag but was unfortunately edited away; I recommend you use [JsonUtility](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html) instead of Newton's library. While his lib is great it doesn't play nice with Unity  and unity already have great support for this built in.

Answer (score 1):

The following splits the string and then parses the integers:

```
var input = "[20,8,25,5,34,12]";   

public static int[] ParseNumbersList(string input) {
    const char valueSeperator = ',';

    var removeBrackets = input.Substring(1, input.Length-2);
    var parts = removeBrackets.Split(valueSeperator);

    return parts.Select(p => int.Parse(p)).ToArray();
}
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f2Wfde)

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting each individual character with

```
List<char> temp = input.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToList();
```

You should instead use the commas in the array to seperate the digits using something like below:

```
List<string> temp = input.Trim(new []{ '[', ']' }).Split(new []{ ',' }).ToList();
```

So remove the brackets, split the array at the commas and this gives you the individual JSON array elements.

Do note that it might be worthwile to use a library for all your JSON parsing, this is something you should to consider.